# What does the :ro in docker command to run nginx do

Tags: docker, nginx

From the [nginx docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx), to run nginx image, we need to:

`docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx`

I understand the option `-v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro` mounts the directory `/some/content` on host to container's `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory.

But what does `:ro` at the end do ?

Comment: `r`ead -`o`nly: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume.

Comment: In my opinion, using `:ro` shorthand is a bad practice - it is not documented anywhere, making the docker syntax harder to understand for new users.

Answer (score 13):

It means [read only volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume). So the container will not be able to modify its contents.